What to do for very short cripple studs?
Say I'm putting in a header in a load-bearing wall.  The heights are such that the gap between the header and the top plate of the wall is too wide for shims but still small.  For example, 1"-3".  I don't want to place the header directly up against the plate and add a nailer at the bottom.  What do I do for cripples at the top?

Any reason not to use a larger header?  A 2x8 instead of a 2x6.  Or use a 2x sideways to fill the space?

@crip659 Top plate may not be flat.  Jack stud height may be restricted and cutting a 2x10 to just the right height  sound fiddly.  Seems like cutting shorty cripple studs should be the easier route if there's a right way to do it.

Cut the cripples to what you need and predrill for screws so they don't split.

Short studs would need pilot holes for screws more than long studs, but are done the same way.  Measure twice and cut to size.  If top plate is at an angle to the header, then the cuts should be at an angle also.

@crip659 Even if they're 2 inches tall?  Should they still be oriented with the grain vertical even if they're wider than they are tall?

I think a professional engineer might say it is stronger one way than the other, but for two inches supported underneath I do not think it matters enough.  Just which way will make the cutting easier to fit.
